# SSIS 2008 Script in C#: need to convert Y2K string to date format and use it to populate variable

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-crm

I am trying to get records from an AS400 system into Dynamics CRM programatically. To achieve this i have pushed the AS400 records into a SQL table and am able to push those records to CRM by referencing the CRM 4 web service endpoints in a SSIS 2008 C# script.

The problem is one of the fields is in Y2K date string format. In order to get it into a date field (D.O.B) in CRM i believe i will need to convert it to a date format then reference resulting value in a variable.

I do not know how to do this.

This question/answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4880021/1326443) may help with part of the question but i do not know how to use this into my script to get a value (haven't done any scripting for a number of years and new to C#)

Script snippet:

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
private CrmService service = null;


public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();


    CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
    token.AuthenticationType = 0;
    token.OrganizationName = "DevOrg";

    service = new CrmService();
    service.Url = "http://crm/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx";
    service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
    service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();

}

public override void LeadInput_ProcessInputRow(LeadInputBuffer Row)
{
    lead cont = new lead();

if (!Row.TITL20_IsNull)

{
        cont.salutation = Row.TITL20;
    }


if (!Row.DOBI20_IsNull)

{
            cont.new_birthdate = Row.DOBI20;
        }

....

....

            service.Create(cont);
        }

    }
}
```

---

`{ cont.new_birthdate = Row.DOBI20; }` throws:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to .....CrmSdk.CRMDateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a look at the documentation for `CRMDateTime` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928935.aspx)

This states that you can set this using the `Value` property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928944.aspx)

So you might like to try:

```
cont.new_birthdate.Value = Row.DOBI20
```

**Edit**

In response to your comments, try the following

```
string ConvertDate(string dateToConvert)
{ 
    dateToConvert= dateToConvert.PadLeft(7, '0');
    int c;
    int.TryParse(dateToConvert.Substring(0,1), out c);  
    c = (c * 100) + 1900;

    int y;
    int.TryParse(dateToConvert.Substring(1,2), out y);  

    return (c+y).ToString() + dateToConvert.Substring(3,4);
}
```

Comment: Hey James, 

Thanks I'll give that a go.To expand on my question: where i referred to (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4880021/1326443) for a bit more scope on my issue. I have a (AS400 style) Y2k string. To paraphrase:

"I am using SSIS (SQL 2008) to bring data over from an AS400. The date values are stored in the 400 as a 7 digit numeric. Here is the format: "CYYMMDD" C is a "century digit" where 0 = 1900 and 1 = 2000. I have been looking into derived columns and script components. ...Also, I am losing leading zeros."

Comment: The suggested answer was:

"

1. ((DT_WSTR,8)(<<AS400>> + 19000000)) 
2. (DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(DCDateString,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(DCDateString,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(DCDateString,7,2))

"

I do have the data in a SQL Server table now so the AS400 system is out of the picture. But how do i get this into my code to pass the value:

    cont.new_birthdate.Value = SomeFunction(Row.DOBI20)???

    

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Think you are right about the value property...The script prefers the following syntax: 
`code` cont.new_birthdate = new CrmDateTime()

Comment: Value = "x"

I will check out your function. Thx

Comment: Can you post your suggested edit as a comment here. It was rejected because its not part of the answer.

Comment: Hi, The `code` dateToConvert= dateToConvert.PadLeft(7, '0'); `code` will add 7 zeros to the front of the string right - quick sanity check... The string will have 1,6 or 7 characters as the leading 0 is stripped and some records have a value of 0.

The function will need to handle this and convert to date format

Comment: The padleft will pad zeros to the left until the length of the ztring is 7. You haven't specified what should happen when it is 0. I.e. what should the date be here. In any istance you should be able to code that yourself with a simple `if` condition.